# How to vertically center text inside navbar <a> tag without using vertical padding

Tags: html, css

I have a nav bar with `height: 5vh` and the rest of the page inside a container with `height: 95vh`. I use `display: flex` for my nav bar `<ul>` element and `align-items: stretch` so that the `<li>` elements have 100% height of the nav bar. Also I set the height of the `<a>` elements to 100% of the parent `<li>` elements.

However, the problem is that I want the text of the `<a>` elements to be vertically aligned to center (not top). I can't set a vertical padding for the `<a>` elements because this will affect the height of the element and will not make its height responsive.

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        nav ul {
            background-color: aquamarine;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 5vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: stretch;
        }

        nav a {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 0 10px;
            height: 100%;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: navy;
        }

        nav a:hover {
            background-color: rgb(95, 206, 169);
        }

        nav a.active {
            background-color: azure;
        }

        .content {
            height: 95vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: silver;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- Nav bar -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!-- Rest of the page -->
    <div class="content"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `vertical-align: middle` on the `inline-block` `<a>`

Comment: Sorry, it's not working

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71402140/2813224) added it to  `<li>` instead of  `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `<a>` to `flex` and use `align-items: center` to align it vertically

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      background-color: aquamarine;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 5vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
    }
    
    nav a {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      padding: 0 10px;
      height: 100%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: navy;
    }
    
    nav a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(95, 206, 169);
    }
    
    nav a.active {
      background-color: azure;
    }
    
    .content {
      height: 95vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: silver;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Nav bar -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Rest of the page -->
  <div class="content"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Fixed the navbar being too short in smaller windows:

```
nav ul {
  min-height: 5vh;
...
```

Didn't see a style for `<li>` so I added it and looks vertically centered on fullpage, but the navbar shrinks drastically when window scales down (this behavior is before any modification).

```
li {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: space-around;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul {
      background-color: aquamarine;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 5vh;
      display: flex;
      align-items: stretch;
    }
    
    li {
      min-height: 100%;
      display: inline-block;
      align-self: space-around;
      vertical-align: bottom;
    }
    
    nav a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 10px;
      min-height: 100%;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: navy;
    }
    
    nav a:hover {
      background-color: rgb(95, 206, 169);
    }
    
    nav a.active {
      background-color: azure;
    }
    
    .content {
      height: 95vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: silver;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Nav bar -->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Rest of the page -->
  <div class="content"></div>

</body>

</html>
```